# How can I use standard WiX to create a streamlined installer experience?

Tags: installation, wix, wix3

**Background**:
Currently, we have created a wizard by WiX UI. The user should click next, next and next...
But suddenly, we found that there's nothing should be interacted with user, user just need keep clicking next. So..

Here is the *desired behavior*:
We automatically switch to the next dialog page after all the stuff (such as pre-check and so on) done in the current page. Once there are errors in installation process, we show the error page to the user. That makes for a streamlined installer experience for the user. One click, everything done.

Can WIX do this kind of stuff purely, or should I need some other work to do to implement this?

Comment: Just want to mention that there seems to be something happening with regards to bootstrapping in wix 3.5, but that's all in beta for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you'll need to define your own external UI handler (like the MS Office installer does) if you want something "fancy" - why not just remove the UI altogether? We do this for a number of setups....

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at WixUI_Mondo, WixUI_Minimal and other predefined UIs that come with WiX. Otherwise you can define your own dialogs and their sequence.

Comment: I knew these dialogs, and am using them, I just wonder if I can switch them automatically without click "Next" button? Any tricks?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Wix_minimal or you can go for your own customized dialog boxes.

You can also customize the sequences of the dialog boxes by your own need. I suggest you to do the second option.